# Why is there a line break in my email preview text in iOS Mail app?

Tags: ios, email, zurb-foundation, html-email

I have created a few HTML emails using [Foundation for Emails](https://foundation.zurb.com/emails/docs/index.html). I am seeing a strange behavior in the iOS Mail app consistently with every email I create. The preview text has a line break in it for some reason. Here's what I mean:

[image]

Instead of showing the entire preview text as a continuous string, it's putting "Thanks" on it's own line.

This is the code for the preview text:

```
<span class="preheader" style="color:#f3f3f3;display:none!important;font-size:1px;line-height:1px;max-height:0;max-width:0;mso-hide:all!important;opacity:0;overflow:hidden;visibility:hidden">Thanks for your order! Your order number is 1538. Please save this order confirmation email for your records.</span>
```

I can't figure out why the preview text is displaying this way. Does anyone have any clue?

Even if I remove the preview text completely, the preview still displays with a line break. For example, if the `.preheader` section is empty, then iOS displays the preview text as:

```
Thanks
For Your...
```

I am very confused. Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

One other thing that might be relevant, besides the styles on the `.preheader` tag, there is also these styles on the `body`, which is the parent of the `.preheader` tag.

```
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;Margin:0;box-sizing:border-box;color:#0a0a0a;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0;min-width:100%;padding:0;text-align:left;width:100%!important
```

Comment: Can anyone help me with this? It's very frustrating and I don't see anything I have done that would cause it. I'm basically just using foundation for email out of the box. It's happening consistently with every message I generate using the framework. Has anyone else seen this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The emails are being sent through BigCommerce. It's an issue with how BigCommerce encodes their emails. BigCommerce adds linebreaks to limit line length, but not properly using 'quoted-printable' encoding to ensure continuous lines remain continuous. Frustrating, but at least there is an explanation. I sent them an explanation so we'll see if it ever gets fixed.